# How to run multiple test suites in another test suite with geb

Tags: testing, groovy, automated-tests, spock, geb

I would like to run all my test suites. I want to call the test suites in one test suit called Allrun. 
Can I call test suites in another test suite. I am looking for something like this:

```
class Myfirst extends GebReportingSpec {

 def myfunction(){
    when:''
    at mypage1

    and:''
     element1.text() == "mytext1"
  }
}

class Mysecond extends GebReportingSpec {

  def mysecondFunction() {
    when:''
    at mypage2

    and:''
     element2.text() == "mytext2"

   }

 }

 class AlltestSuites extends GebReportingSpec {
     Myfirst myfirst = new Myfirst ()
     Mysecond  mysecond = new Mysecond ()


    def allrun(){
          myfirst.myfunction() 
          mysecond.mysecondFunction()
      }


  }
```

How can i do this? Does anyone has an idea

Comment: Do you need it in a specific order? or just to run all `*Spec`

Comment: I do not understand the question. Maven and/or your IDE should do that for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a AllRun.groovy file like below to run all class files in the specified order [Myfirst.class, Mysecond.class, etc].

```
package geb.groovy

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.Suite
import geb.groovy.scripts.Myfirst
import geb.groovy.scripts.Mysecond


@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses([Myfirst.class, Mysecond.class])
class CustomJUnitSpecRunner {
}
```

And in build.gradle systemProperties System.properties, exclude the individual Myfirst.class, Mysecond.class files. So that they run only once through AllRun file.

```
include 'geb/groovy/AllRun/**'
exclude 'geb/groovy/scripts/**'
```

Answer (score 0):

Groups of specs can be run using the command below, where `package` is a directory under `src/test/groovy/specs`:

```
mvn test -Dtest=specs.package.*
```

If you are relying on specs to be run in a particular order, I would reconsider your approach.  If you require data in a certain state then make use of setup() and setupSpec() methods. Also consider running related tests within a single spec and run these in the order the are written by using the @Stepwise annotation.

```
@Stepwise
class MyStepWiseTest extends GebReportingSpec {

 def myfunction(){
    when:''
    at mypage1

    and:''
     element1.text() == "mytext1"
  }

  def mysecondFunction() {
    when:''
    at mypage2

    and:''
     element2.text() == "mytext2"

   }
}
```